# Can I travel to any part of the US on a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, usa

I am planning to visit the US for tourism. Until now I have never been to any foreign country.

I want to know whether the visa is issued for a stay in a particular city or whether I can travel to any part of the country?

Answer (score 21):

They're for the whole country. There are [no controls on the movement of people within the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_movement_under_United_States_law), except for the usual requirements to show ID to get on a plane. In particular, if you drive across a state border, you will typically see *absolutely nothing* except a sign saying what state you're in now.  A few states, such as California, have agricultural inspection stations near the border but these are designed to prevent the free movement of agricultural pests, not people. There are also some [interior border patrol checkpoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Border_Patrol_interior_checkpoints), which are on highways around 50 miles from the Mexican border and designed to prevent illegal immigration and smuggling.  You'd be required to show your papers there but, as long as you're legally in the country, you're free to pass through.

Since Alaska and Hawaii are disconnected from the other 48 states, there are some small differences with them. Getting to Alaska overland requires going through Canada so isn't travel purely within the US, even though it's travel from one part of the US to another.  To do that overland, you'd need to leave the US and then re-enter; flying to Alaska doesn't count as leaving the US, even though you'd fly over Canada from most places.  There are also differences if you travel by private boat or private plane but I'm assuming you won't be doing that.

(It would be nice to back up this answer with a link to some sort of official advice but I've no idea where to look for that, since it seems unlikely that there are lists of all the things that *aren't* required. You don't have to drive a red car, you don't have to carry an umbrella, etc.)

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out that there are areas you can't go (basically certain government sites), but that applies to all people (except those given special permission) and should be signposted. You could also contrast the US with countries that do require additional permits for visiting certain regions eg. China, Russia. Also worth noting that (for a single entry visa at least) if your travels don't seem to line up with what you said in the visa application, that **can** cause problems.

Comment: getting to Alaska by car or boat, or Hawaii by boat, is likely to require other paperwork because it will involve going into another country on the way there. This isn't an issue by plane and I'm prepared to say it's an edge case, but it is probably worth mentioning.

Comment: @CMaster Everywhere has areas you can't go (government sites, private property, all kinds of things), so I don't think that's worth mentioning. Explicitly stating that there are no internal movement controls within the US seems enough of a contrast with countries that do have internal movement controls.

Comment: @KateGregory Good point about Alaska but how does going to Hawaii require passing through any other country?

Comment: @KateGregory furthermore, it's possible to get to Alaska without entering Canadian territorial waters. Even if you do, I wouldn't be surprised if they only look at your passport if you stop somewhere.

Comment: @DavidRicherby even though a trip from the west coast to Hawaii doesn't necessarily pass through another country, it is likely that you'd need to show your papers on arrival. I don't know whether that would count as a new "entry" of the US, but its certainly possible that it would.

Comment: @phoog Isn't the situation for arriving in Hawaii by scheduled commercial transport (boat or plane) identical to arriving in any other state? Sure, your cruise ship could have stopped off in Canada to pick up illegal immigrants but it didn't, just like your flight.

Comment: your cruise ship, yes. Your personal sailboat, no. But we are wandering offtopic surely.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You seemed to be searching for something clearer to stay - was coming up with elements that seem relevant.

Comment: @phoog OK, sure, but I have a sneaking suspicion that anybody asking the question at the top of the page would appreciate that buying a boat and sailing it to Hawaii is going to be a special case. The question is not asking about this kind of thing.

Comment: There are also [interior border patrol checkpoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Border_Patrol_interior_checkpoints) near the US/Mexico border.

Comment: @StrongBad They've very close to the border (within 50km in almost all cases), and you'd really have to try to go to one of them if you're not heading to Mexico.  But worth mentioning for sure.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning inspection stations, contrary to "you will see absolutely nothing except a sign". Those are typically not directly at the state borders (at least the inspection station from Oregon to California), but fairly close. Although it is only related (and therefore I wouldn't expect to see this in an answer), it would be worth mentioning toll roads and the kind of *fun* they can provide to an unsuspecting tourist.

Comment: Crossing state borders is a right protected by law: [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_movement_under_United_States_law)

Comment: Does the Alaska Marine Highway require a passport? I've never taken it, does it make calls in Canadian ports.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Based on their [web site](http://www.dot.state.ak.us/amhs/), they do not specifically require a passport, though some form of government-issued id is required. And based on [the system map](http://www.dot.state.ak.us/amhs/routes.shtml) (pop-up from that page) they do not provide service to Canada.

Comment: @Thebluefish The inspection station at the Oregon-California border? What is it there for? I've never crossed that border but I've never seen anything of that kind before.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Perhaps that's another question to ask, then.

Comment: They were stopping people on the Oregon California border to confiscate oranges. Seriously. My father-in-law ate three oranges right in front of them rather than give them up. I didn't even know it was legal to do that.

Comment: @Joe - the San Clemente station is on the northbound I-5 between Orange County & San Diego (heading AWAY from Mexico, and pretty far from the border). I've seen traffic stopped there while travelling south, but I've never been stopped heading north.

Comment: @corsiKa If there's a legitimate threat to public health, then they can do that (and I've seen it in other places in the midwest), but it's rare.  California is the main exception, likely because it is the source of much of our produce.  See [this chart](https://www.cdfa.ca.gov/plant/factsheets/BringingFruitsVeggies_to_CA.pdf) for more detail on what is prohibited to be brought into CA.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai http://www.yelp.com/map/state-of-california-food-and-agriculture-dept-inspection-station-hornbrook This is the specific one I regularly pass through. Typically friendly until you have certain produce on you.

Comment: @Joe my concern isn't whether or not it's a good idea, merely of whether it's constitutional. If that makes any sense.

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, I understand, and that is why I said if there is a legitimate threat.  They could do the same thing in other locations (for a dramatic example, the quarantines of citizens for Ebola exposure) if there were a threat.  (I'm not a constitutional lawyer, though, so I'd be curious what happened when these issues have gone to the court, assuming they have... )

Comment: @Joe Considering the "Ye Haw shoot shoot bang bang bullet bullet gun" nature of southern Oregon, I can't imagine they haven't taken it to court some time in the last 7 years...

Comment: There are agricultural checkpoints when entering California on major highways, mainly to stop the spread of Mediterranean fruit flies into the state. If you are driving a car with California or neighboring license plates, they will likely wave you through. They aren't there to check your ID or prevent the movement of people, so it's irrelevant to the question about tourist visas.

Comment: @corsiKa the agricultural inspection has been in place for decades. It was probably litigated far longer than seven years ago.

Comment: @Joe the internal checkpoints can be within 100 miles of the external border (161 km), measured directly rather than along the road. They also exist along the Canadian border, though I'm not sure they've gotten around to building any permanent stations; they mostly set them up temporarily in rest areas. Two locations I know about are North Hudson, NY, and on I-91 in Vermont just south of its intersection with I-89.